# django update portion of a template dynamically post a model save without re rendering

Tags: python, django

I have a side bar in my template with three event columns (All, Active, Inactive). The activity of the items in the side bar is controlled in backend.

I want to dynamically update the list of events shown under (Active, Inactive), when ever their status changes and saved into the database.

I can do this by constantly making an Ajax Request and update the template based on the response from view.

But I was wondering if django signals can be used and post_save trigger and update the items on the template. Please let me know if u need more details.

Code snippets:

```
<!-- sidebar -->
<div class="container">

    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="side-filter-header">
        <a class="selected">All Events</a>
          <a class="" >Active Events</a>
          <a class="" >Inactive Events</a>
      </div>

      <div class="side-filter-list">

        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active-event">
            <ul>
              <li>Event 1</li>
            </ul>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="list-group-item inactive-event">
          <ul>
            <li>Event 2 </li>
          </ul>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="list-group-item inactive-event">
          <ul>
            <li>Event 3</li>
          </ul>
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Django models.py

```
class EventStatus(Enum):
    ACTIVE = "ACTIVE"
    INACTIVE = "INACTIVE"

class Event(models.model):
   eventNo = models.IntegerField()
   eventStatus = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=EventStatus.INACTIVE, choices=[(tag,tag.value) for tag in EventStatus])
```

Django views.py

```
def update_sidebar():
   event = Event.objects.filter().last() # example
   # some condition
   event.eventStatus = "ACTIVE"
   event.save()  # I want to trigger the view here. What would be the best and efficient way?
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    event = Event.objects.filter().last() # example
    # some condition
    event.eventStatus = "ACTIVE"
    super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Could you tell me how would this super().save() call update my template?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the information about the model change needs to get to the user side browser and needs to be displayed. You mentioned already the Javascript/Ajax method which would be a pull (and in my opinion the standard way). The other possibilty is web push or web notification ... please google. But as far as I know they need always the user to consent to receiving push messages and many user (including myself) just decline any request to allow push messages because of potential spam.